Setting Context | Gettig value off TransactionSynconizationMananger.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly()
I'm trying to dynamic route my transactions to the READ_WRITE or READ_ONLY datasources.
But in my class TransactionRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource
when i am trying to get the value of TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly()
it always returns false.
I already try to set a context using a custom annotation, but the context is setting after when i want to use it, to route my transactions, can anyone help me?
Just getting a infomation in the TransactionRoutingDataSource will solve my problem.
I tested with default values (DataSourceType.READ_WRITE & DataSourceType.READ_ONLY) and it works, the transaction is routed to the correct Database
TransactionRoutingDataSource
package com.example.wsappsiav.MultipleDatabase.Configuration.Teste;

import com.example.wsappsiav.MultipleDatabase.Properties.DatabaseContextHolder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;



public class TransactionRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionRoutingDataSource.class);
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        boolean isReadOnly = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly();
        LOGGER.info("Routed to : " + DatabaseContextHolder.getEnvironment());
        LOGGER.info("isReadOnly : " + isReadOnly);

        return DatabaseContextHolder.getEnvironment();
    }
}

ReadReplicaAspect
package com.example.wsappsiav.MultipleDatabase;

import com.example.wsappsiav.MultipleDatabase.Configuration.Teste.DataSourceType;
import com.example.wsappsiav.MultipleDatabase.Properties.DatabaseContextHolder;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;


@Aspect
@Component
public class ReadReplicaAspect {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReadReplicaAspect.class);
    @Around("@annotation(com.example.wsappsiav.MultipleDatabase.annotations.UseReadReplica)")
    public Object routeToReadReplica(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.info("Setting database context to " + DataSourceType.READ_ONLY);
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.setCurrentTransactionReadOnly(true);
        LOGGER.info("Transaction Mananger: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly());
        DatabaseContextHolder.set(DataSourceType.READ_ONLY);
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}

ClienteService
@Service
public class ClienteService {
    @Autowired
    private ClienteRepository clienteRepository;
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    @UseReadReplica
    public List<Cliente> listarTodosClientes() {
        return clienteRepository.findAll();}

ReplicaDataSource
package com.example.wsappsiav.MultipleDatabase.Configuration.replica;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface ReplicaDataSource {
}

LOG'S
2024-05-14T10:13:08.676-03:00  INFO 15568 --- [ws-app-siav] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.w.M.C.T.TransactionRoutingDataSource : Routed to : null

2024-05-14T10:13:08.676-03:00  INFO 15568 --- [ws-app-siav] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.w.M.C.T.TransactionRoutingDataSource : isReadOnly : false

2024-05-14T10:13:08.868-03:00  INFO 15568 --- [ws-app-siav] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.w.M.ReadReplicaAspect                : Setting database context to READ_ONLY

2024-05-14T10:13:08.868-03:00  INFO 15568 --- [ws-app-siav] [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.w.M.ReadReplicaAspect                : Transaction Mananger: true

2024-05-14T10:13:08.947-03:00 DEBUG 15568 --- [ws-app-siav] [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select c1_0.id,c1_0.cliente_nome,c1_0.cpf_cnpj,c1_0.email,c1_0.endereco,c1_0.telefone from bd_siav.cliente c1_0

Hibernate: select c1_0.id,c1_0.cliente_nome,c1_0.cpf_cnpj,c1_0.email,c1_0.endereco,c1_0.telefone from bd_siav.cliente c1_0

application.properties
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true

spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode = MANUAL


spring.jpa.show-sql=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true


Ignore the tag 'Propagation.MADATORY', i was just trying kkkkkk
i already try 'Propagation.REQUIRE_NEW'

Solved. JUST IN VERSION 6.1.2
I remove the configurations of TransactionRoutingDataSource, and add
LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy lazyDateSource = new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(dataSource);
lazyDateSource.setReadOnlyDataSource(dataSourceReader);

i view in this question
